# Devise skip confirmation when using omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

How can I change the following code so that a user that signs in with facebook gets to skip the confirmation with devise confirmable?  I tried adding `user.skip_confirmation!` under the line `user.email...` but this did not work.

user.rb:

```
# Finds or creates user based on omniauth hash from given provider
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.email = auth.info.email
    end
  end

  # Overrides class method 'new_with_session' to persist and validate attributes
  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else  
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :facebook, :all
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this with `first_or_initialize`:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid). first_or_initialize do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.skip_confirmation!
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

Comment: I actually added the line `user.confirmed_at = Time.zone.now` and it seems to be working.  Can you see any issues doing it this way vs your suggestion?  Thanks

Comment: you can use `user.confirm` @user4584963
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirm-instance_method

Comment: @user4584963  It is practically the same thing, but `skip_confirmation!` was made for a reason. As far as I know, better coding practice. See the  [docs for it here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FConfirmable%3Askip_confirmation%21)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the simplest way, just adding `user.skip_confirmation!` in the method  referred in the [documentation](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#devise) does work now:

```
 # app/model/user.rb

  def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(email: data['email']).first

    # Users are created if they don't exist
    unless user
      user = User.create(username: data['name'],
                         email: data['email'],
                         password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20])
      user.skip_confirmation! # Add this line to skip confirmation
    end
    user
  end
```

If you want to skip both confirmation and the email confirmation notification (which would make sense), you'll just need to add `user.skip_confirmation!` before saving the user, which you can do like this:

```
 # app/model/user.rb

  def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(email: data['email']).first

    # Users are created if they don't exist
    unless user
      user = User.new(username: data['name'],
                      email: data['email'],
                      password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20])
      user.skip_confirmation! # Add this line to skip confirmation
      user.save
    end
    user
  end
```